# How to make svg squares responsive?

Tags: css, svg

How to make these sequares be responsive by the parent element?

```html
   <svg style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" id="square">
     <g>
      <rect height="50" width="50" y="0" x="0" stroke-width="2" stroke="gray" fill="#B0b0b0"/>
      <rect height="50" width="50" y="50" x="50" stroke-width="2" stroke="gray" fill="#B0b0b0"/>
      <rect height="50" width="50" y="0" x="50" stroke-width="2" stroke="gray" fill="#B0b0b0"/>
      <rect height="50" width="50" y="50" x="0" stroke-width="2" stroke="gray" fill="#B0b0b0"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: you mean they can be distorted depending on the width/height?

Comment: Yes, I want to set:  `<div style="height:600px;width:600px;"><svg>…`

Comment: why not using CSS? it's easier

Comment: Yes, But I need to do in svg.. as logo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use viewBox to `"0 0 100 100"`.

[Scale SVG](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/)

Here the solution:

```
 <div style="width: 400px; height: 400px;border:1px solid red;">

           <svg id="square" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                <g>
                    <rect height="50" width="50" y="0" x="0" stroke-width="2" stroke="gray" fill="#B0b0b0"/>
                    <rect height="50" width="50" y="50" x="50" stroke-width="2" stroke="gray" fill="#B0b0b0"/>
                    <rect height="50" width="50" y="0" x="50" stroke-width="2" stroke="gray" fill="#B0b0b0"/>
                    <rect height="50" width="50" y="50" x="0" stroke-width="2" stroke="gray" fill="#B0b0b0"/>
                </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using CSS and background then it will be easy to change the size:

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:
    linear-gradient(gray,gray),
    linear-gradient(gray,gray),
    #B0b0b0;
  background-size:100% 2px,2px 100%;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border:1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
<div class="box" style="width:200px;height:200px;">

</div>
```

With SVG you can consider percentage value:

```css
rect {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<svg style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" id="square">
     <g>
      <rect  y="0" x="0" stroke-width="2" stroke="gray" fill="#B0b0b0"/>
      <rect  y="50%" x="50%" stroke-width="2" stroke="gray" fill="#B0b0b0"/>
      <rect  y="0" x="50%" stroke-width="2" stroke="gray" fill="#B0b0b0"/>
      <rect y="50%" x="0" stroke-width="2" stroke="gray" fill="#B0b0b0"/>
     </g>
    </svg>

<svg style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" id="square">
     <g>
      <rect  y="0" x="0" stroke-width="2" stroke="gray" fill="#B0b0b0"/>
      <rect  y="50%" x="50%" stroke-width="2" stroke="gray" fill="#B0b0b0"/>
      <rect  y="0" x="50%" stroke-width="2" stroke="gray" fill="#B0b0b0"/>
      <rect y="50%" x="0" stroke-width="2" stroke="gray" fill="#B0b0b0"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: This is not responsive. The code you have provided is set.

Answer (score -2):

If you like to create a responsive element there is a very nice trick. You can adapt it to any ratio you want with `padding-top:100%;` you obtain a 1:1 ratio.

```css
.ratio{
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}
.ratio:before{
  content: '\0020';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
.box{
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="ratio">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```